# when I run this, It says "argument of type 'int' is not iterable" what can I do to solve it?

Tags: python-3.x

This is a python code. I was working on a problem and this is just a block of code from that programme? Can anyone help me to figure this out. I'm a beginner so please explain it carefully.

```
def checking(p,q):
    for i in range(0,3):
        if q[i] == p[i]:
            print('Match')
        elif q[i] in p[i]:
            print('Close')
        else:
            print('Nope')

p = [2,5,7]
q = [3,6,7]
checking(p,q)
```

I expect Match as my output. but the actual output is a typeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Comment: `elif q[i] in p[i]:` is not correct. What are you trying to test here?

Comment: The issue is with searching for q[i] in an integer. If you are looking for an element of q[i] in p, using `q[i] in p` would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
        elif q[i] in p[i]:
            print('Close')
```

`in` operates on things that are iterable such as lists and dicts. Here you're trying to see if an item from the first list is part of *an item* in the second list and this is why python is complaining: Both `q[i]` and `p[i]` are integers and you try to iterate over the second as if it is a list.

I assume this is a typo and I would suggest:

```
        elif q[i] in p:
            print('Close')
```